# jQuery - Hooking into an $.ajax call from an outside script

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, hook

I'm including a script "foo.js" that I want to modify:

```
<head>
    <script src="/myPath/foo.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
</head>
```

To be able to hook into an ajax call on my main page:

```
$.ajax({
    url: urlPath,
    success: function (data) {
        //hook into here from foo.js somehow??
    }
});
```

Is there any way to do this solely in foo.js without modifying the main page's script at all? (perhaps hook into a call inside the main script that is filling out/changing content?)

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to call a function defined in `foo.js` in your ajax success handler?

Comment: No, I want to completely leave my ajax success handler alone but script foo.js so that it alters data that is returned in that call.

Answer (score 5):

You can try to use a [Global Ajax Event Handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) for listning global events.

Comment: These are great, however it looks like you can't alter the data in the  xhr.responseText object that it returns? However, I did get a solution working using ajaxSuccess() and window.setInterval() - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your `foo.js` is wrapped in a closure (**if you don't know what this means, just ignore)** then you can bind to a namespace and call functions through there.

Otherwise, javascript has a global scope so any scripts imported into your file will have the ability to call functions as long as it is imported in order of dependencies.

ie:

foo.js:

```
function foo(data) {
   // do stuff with data
}
```

main.html:

```
<head>
   <script src="/myPath/foo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $.ajax({
          url: urlPath,
          success: function(data) {
              foo(data);
          }
       });
   </script>
 </head>
```

It's important that the embedded script comes **AFTER** the import so that it can make reference to functions inside `foo.js`.

Comment: Like I was saying, I don't want to alter what is in "main.html" at all, including adding a call to foo(data);

I just need to hook into the success of that ajax call through the external script.